# Where did my network-scripts go?

Tags: linux, centos

I am currently trying to set up a network bridge. Basically, I modified some files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`
and messed something up to the point where I could no longer access the internet with the current ethernet connection I had. So I looked up how to reset my network settings to default and basically said to remove the files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ (I did back up the folder before doing anything) and then ran

```
$systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Basically it just deleted files like ifcfg-eno1np0, ifcfg-eno2np1,etc. Then I restarted the computer itself and I was able to regain internet service and when I run

```
$ifconfig
```

it looks like all my settings are back and internet service works but when I go back to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/, I don't see any of the files, ifcfg-eno1np0, ifcfg-eno2p1, etc back in that directory so where are the current network settings being stored since it apparently did return back to its default state?

Comment: Which CentOS version are you using? NetworkManager uses plugins to read/write connections' configuration files. Depending on the in-use plugin, configuration files may be stored in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` (see `man nm-settings-ifcfg-rh`), in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` (see `man nm-settings-keyfile`) or somewhere else. You may be able (depending on your NetworkManager version) to list the in-use plugins with `NetworkManager --print-config`.

Comment: have you tried searching for them with the find command?

Comment: yes, the only thing listed where those files went were in the folders I backed up the files in when i used the find command

Comment: this is centos 8

Comment: when i run the command nmcli conn show --active i get all connections to show but i don't understand how it was able to return to default if those files like ifcfg-eno1np0 were deleted?

Comment: I don't know CentOS, but if similar to Ubuntu, it moved to `/etc/netplan`, some .yaml file in there... and it gets managed with `netplan ...` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I did use nmcli to set up my network environment and I realized that the configuration file is located in this path route

```
sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/enp0s3.nmconnection
```

I'm using fedora server and enp0s3 is the name of my network interface.